# Connecting with Win 2008r2 to Mac OS

Tags: mac, windows-server-2008

Our main server in the operations of one of my clients in on a IMac Pro (Mac Mojave) We run a specific financial program on said machine.

A new version of the financial program is getting ready for testing on our systems. It is not OS dependent. We have 2 test Win Machines, one standalone and one virtual (Using VMware) on the Mac . They run 2008 server R2. No matter what I can do I cannot get the Win machines to see the Mac. The Mac sees the Win machines fine and can access anything I want on them, but the reverse is not true. One of our Win 10 laptops has no issue with see back and forth to the Mac machine.

What gives and any suggestions of how to get the Win 2008 machies to see and access the Mac?

Thanks for your help.
Tom in Dallas/Plano

Answer (score 1):

The Server 2008 machine is running SMBv1 which is the main cause of connection issues with newer machines not using SMBv1 (SMBv2 or greater instead).

[Server 2008 SMB version](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/84aa9472-630c-4cdb-939e-dfa5f406f473/need-to-check-smb-connection-version-on-windows-2008-r2-windows-7)

Server 2008 is well out of support and no upgrades for it.

There is a registry key to check version, but I do not see any way to upgrade the SMB version.

I do not recommend it but you can consider downgrading SMB on newer machines. This is a security risk and I do not recommend it.

You could consider a good strong Windows 10 machine as a "Server" for testing purposes.